# Set body width for StyledDocument (JTextPane)

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I can do this and my rich text will have fixed width

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
pane.setContentType("text/html");
pane.setText("<html><body style='width:100px'>Some text</body></html>");
```

But I work directly with Document, without HTML. How can I set width?

```
DefaultStyledDocument doc = (DefaultStyledDocument) pane.getStyledDocument();
//??? (set width)
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, try to `setMinimumSize` for `pane`.

Comment: Why don't you set the size off the component instead of doing it through the document ?

Answer (score 0):

The width is not part of model (the Document). There should be a View to handle the width attribute from the Document and set the width accordingly.

You should replace the root view (SectionView) in your EditorKit's ViewFactory to return custom view with width taken from the Document element.

See for example the link
http://java-sl.com/Pagination_In_JEditorPane.html

It describe how to add pagination to the EditorKit. You can use the code as example and fix the width only.

```
Extend EditorKit.
Replace default ViewFactory with yours
Replace root view (SectionView)
Replace the view's getPreferredSpan(int axis) for X axis to use the width from the Document
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides Document is StyledDocument but also that has just two levels: paragraph and characters. In this case one might use [HTMLDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html) and either construct it with a CSS Stylesheet (`body { width: 14cm; }`) or alter the CSS stylesheet appropriately.